# Problem with no numbering \subsection*{} - getting "Missing number, treated as zero" error

Tags: sectioning, titles, titlesec, subsection, unnumbered-sections

I have the following subsection within my latex in overleaf:

```
\subsection*{\textbf{Musical Notations}}
```

The * sign is added in order to avoid numbering of this subsection as offered in the overleaf documentation: [https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_remove_the_numbers_from_section_headings%3F#:~:text=If%20you'd%20prefer%20your,table%20of%20contents%20%5Ctableofcontents.)](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_remove_the_numbers_from_section_headings%3F#:%7E:text=If%20you%27d%20prefer%20your,table%20of%20contents%20%5Ctableofcontents.))

I am getting two errors for this. The overleaf manages to compile the latex and generate a pdf but this is problematic for me as I am trying to submit the file to arxiv and it is blocking my upload. The errors are the following:

The first is this:

> A number should have been here; I inserted 0.
> (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
> look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

The second is this:

> Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
> cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
> I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
> To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
> delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
> two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SE. Are you sure that the single line of code you showed is the cause of the problem? Remember that Overleaf has a very poor handling of errors. You should first build a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and post it here with the error log. Also: why use `\textbf` in a title that is already in bold ny default?

Comment: Yes, the errors are on that line precisely. Regarding the \textbf, when I add the * after the subsection the title is shown to me without being bold, and this why I added it.

Comment: I doubt it. I just tried typing that line in a new LaTeX file, and it causes no error. It very likely comes from something before it in your code, and Overleaf makes a mess by trying to ignore it and force compilation (generating a cascade of errors). Hence my request to see a MWE.

Comment: Please at least have an MWE for the mentioned \subsection*{}

Comment: I would guess you have a error on an earlier line, which may also explain why the heading was not bold, but as you have not shown any code or an error message it is impossible to guess.